# How can I prevent views from overlapping in relative layout?

Tags: android

Right now, I have two `TextView`'s. One is aligned to the left of the `RelativeLayout` and one aligned to the right. The `TextView` on the left is much longer than the one on the right. On some occasions, the `TextView` on the left is two lines. When this happens it overlaps the `TextView` that is aligned to the right.

Is there a way to prevent this? Or is there a way to say if the `TextView` on the left is two lines, to put the `TextView` on the right on the second line?

I'm having trouble with name and time down here:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:text="address"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/address"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/address"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/address"
        android:id="@+id/crossStreet"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:text="Time"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Could you instead contain those two TextViews within a horizontal LinearLayout (which itself would still be a child of your RelativeLayout). Then, assign appropriate weight attributes to each of the two TextViews within that LinearLayout.

Comment: awesome. it worked. I also made the time align to the right of the linear layout, for future reference.

Comment: Am I supposed to play around with the weights? I have .35 and .65 to make it work, but .4 and .6 yielded funny results

Answer (score 25):

To get same result using `RelativeLayout` please use `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_text"`. It will position the right edge of this view to the left of the given anchor view ID.

Please follow this example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_material_small"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_material_small">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/long_text"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        tools:text="Some text field that will definitely overlap with another one" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right_text"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        tools:text="10.34" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtext"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/long_text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        tools:text="Some other text slightly smaller"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Result of above layout:

[image: Result of attached example]

Comment: This is certainly preferable to the currently accepted answer. There is no need to nest another container (linear layout) inside a relative layout. You want to reduce nesting containers as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Best Fix:

```
android:layout_toStartOf="@id/item_on_the_right"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code more helpful to you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="1.0" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:text="TextView1 hhhhh hhhhhhhh hhhhhhhh hhhhhhh hhhhhh"
            android:id="@+id/name" android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10sp" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"></TextView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:id="@+id/time" android:text="Textview4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10sp"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeParent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleLeft"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageRight"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />
</RelativeLayout>



android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageRight"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

did the trick without adding additional LinearLayout